# Как получить ВЕСЬ URL-адрес

Tags: python, flask, url

интересует вопрос с получением полного url-адреса на Flask.

*Пример адреса*:
https://testepythonflask.ru/?name=Ivan&lastname=Ivanov#access-token=1abeW3if7seKsb193hdbJsn7bsbJs

Если попытаться достать адрес с помощью request.url, то он возвращает:

`https://testepythonflask.ru/?name=Ivan&lastname=Ivanov`

Тем самым обрезая комментарий.
Каким образом можно получить весь URL-адрес?

Comment: На сервере никак.  Браузер туда просто не посылает всё что после решётки.

Comment: @AlexeyTen Спасибо за помощь